# Cannot find directory for linker -lgomp

Tags: gcc, linker, openmp, python-c-api

I am on an M1 Mac and I have Homebrew GCC installed. I am trying to multithread using OpenMP.

I have a `setup.py` file containing:

```
                  sources = ['pyTsetlinMachineParallel/ConvolutionalTsetlinMachine.c', 'pyTsetlinMachineParallel/MultiClassConvolutionalTsetlinMachine.c', 'pyTsetlinMachineParallel/Tools.c'],
                  include_dirs=['pyTsetlinMachineParallel'],
                  extra_compile_args=['-fopenmp'],
                  extra_link_args=['-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11 -lgomp' ])
```

When I build the file, I get the error:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11 -lgomp'
```

In `/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11` I have these files:
`libgomp.1.dylib` `libgomp.a` `libgomp.dylib` `libgomp.spec`

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: Did you try replacing the `extra_link_args=['-L/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/11.2.0_3/lib/gcc/11 -lgomp' ]` by just `extra_link_args=['-fopenmp']`?

Comment: @Gilles I tried that just now and it gave me ```OSError: dlopen(/Users/Saram/Desktop/University/Individual Project/Code Directory/pyTsetlinMachineParallel/TsetlinVenv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyTsetlinMachineParallel-0.2.1-py3.7-macosx-12-x86_64.egg/libTM.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 0x0006): symbol not found in flat namespace '___kmpc_for_static_fini'```